# What is the right way to create a SSECustomerKey for boto3 file encryption in python?

Tags: python, encryption, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am using boto3 with my django application to upload media to S3. But I am having trouble encrypting the files on server using "Server Side Encryption using Customer Provided Encryption Keys"

I'm using boto3's object.put() api to upload files and specify the encryption keys. But I am getting the following error.

> "The calculated MD5 hash of the key did not match the hash that was
>   provided."

I am not sure on how to create the md5 of the key that will match on the server side. here is my code.

```
password = "32characterslongpassphraseneeded".encode('utf-8')
encryption_key = hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
encryption_key_md5 = hashlib.md5(encryption_key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
key = s3.Object(bucket_name, key_name)
kwargs = {
            'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'AES256',
            'SSECustomerKey': encryption_key,
            'SSECustomerKeyMD5': encryption_key_md5,
            'ContentType': file_obj.content_type,
            'Body': file_obj,
        }

key.put(**kwargs)
```

I am utilizing the same s3 api through a php client and it works fine.

```
$name="somename"
$customerKey = md5($name);
                    $s3->putObject([
                        'Bucket' => S3_BUCKET,
                        'Key'    => "scope/{$name}",
                        'Body'   => fopen($tmp_file_path, 'rb'),
                        'ACL'    => S3_ACL,
                        'SSECustomerAlgorithm' => 'AES256',
                        'SSECustomerKey'       => $customerKey,
                        'SSECustomerKeyMD5'    => md5($customerKey ,true),
                    ]);
```

The only difference I see here is that php's md5 method can take second argument which, if true, returns and 16 character long digest as compared to normal 32 character long digest. Now I don't know how to create a 16 character long digest using hashlib.md5.

Comment: What happens if you don't provide the ``SSECustomerKeyMD5`` param?  Boto3 should calculate it for you.

Comment: If I don't provide it then I receive the 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: The SSECustomerKey and MD5 are suppose to be in base64, hence the mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do is to use `os.urandom`

```
import os
secret_key = os.urandom(32) # The key needs to be 32 character long.
```

and one doesn't need to provide `SSECustomerKeyMD5` as boto3 calculates it for you.

and also SSE-C doesn't work right in `key.put`, as for now, I don't know for what reasons. One has to do it this way.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was clueless for almost a day.

Comment: What would you do to get presigned URL when you upload files like this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems SSE works with `Object` too. An example is as follows

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 
                    region_name="us-east-1",
                    aws_access_key_id="key id",
                    aws_secret_access_key="access key",
                    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')) 
s3.Object("bucket", "filename").put(Body="text",
                                    SSEKMSKeyId="some id",
                                    ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms')
```

To read it, use

```
s3.Object("bucket", "filename").get()['Body'].read()
```