# An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: The calculated MD5 hash of the key did not match the hash that was provided

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, md5

How do i create md5 hash for file object in python flask? I have tried creating using below code:

```
md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
md5_hash.update(file)
digest = md5_hash.hexdigest()
base64_encoded_md5 = base64.b64encode(digest.encode("utf-8"))
base64_encoded_md5_string = str(base64_encoded_md5.decode("utf-8"))
```

I am using SSE-C encryption in boto3 s3_client.upload_fileobj() function, so also passing SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey and SSECustomerKeyMD5 in ExtraArgs.

Here, SSECustomerKeyMD5 is above base64_encoded_md5_string value.

Is there anything wrong in my implementation to get MD5 hash?

How is amazon creating MD5 hash for same file object?

Is there any inbuilt functions in boto3 dependency using which i can get MD5 hash value?

---

I debugged the whole issue, boto3.s3.inject contains upload_fileobj() function. It is uploading the file and in response, returning below response in image.
[boto3.s3.inject response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DkKZ.png)

I am beating my head against this problem for many days. Please help.

---

[SOLVED]:
Modified my encryption key generation algorithm to generate 32 bits string. Earlier it was 16bits which was causing the problem. Also removed the SSECustomerKeyMD5 from ExtraArgs in upload_fileobj() since boto3 internally calculates an MD5 hash for encryption key itself and adds it to request headers before making the actual request in botocore.client._make_api_call.

In short,

1. Removed SSECustomerKeyMD5 from ExtraArgs
2. Modified CustomerKey/EncryptionKey generation algorithm to generate 32 bit string.

Followed shimo's answer and [What is the right way to create a SSECustomerKey for boto3 file encryption in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844349/what-is-the-right-way-to-create-a-ssecustomerkey-for-boto3-file-encryption-in-py) this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find this explanation in [Boto3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html), thought it's not in upload_fileobj section.

> SSECustomerKeyMD5 (string) -- Specifies the 128-bit MD5 digest of the
> encryption key according to RFC 1321.

Your code seems calculating MD5 of file, not encryption key.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer worked. Maybe i was ignoring reading the whole line and thought to pass file object there. Now I have removed SSECustomerKeyMD5 from ExtraArgs and also modified the encryption key generation algorithm to generate 32bits string. earlier it was 16bits which was also causing the problem.